# Elastic Search: Why my filtered query returns nothing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get the result of documents which contains the word "Obama" in their titles using filter. this query returns nothing but the second one using query returns 17000 results.
Using Filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": "Obama"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "Obama"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "filter" means *exclude*. The two queries fundamentally do not do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is not analyzed (Term).
The second one is (Match).

If you change the first one to 'obama' (lowercase), it will work.

Why? Because your text has been analyzed at index time and the inverted index contains 'obama' and not 'Obama'.